# why is there tensor.dtype and tensor.type()?

Tags: python, pytorch

Quick question.
Why does a tensor have a type and a dtype attribute?

```
t = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4])
print(t.dtype, t.type())
```

is it possible to change one of them without changing the other? if not why is there this redundancy? Does it serve any purpose?

Comment: The `dtype` attribute was inherited from `numpy`.  Perhaps the torch authors wanted all of their objects to have a `type()` method.  The real answer is "don't worry about it".

Comment: yes I won't worry about it. so it is just a legacy thing that keeps getting inherited to newer versions because who wants to refactor for something that does not matter :)

Comment: That's exactly right.  These attributes have zero impact on performance, and if there is code relying on these names, why stir the pot?

Answer (score 1):

The `Tensor.type(dtype=None)` function has the ability to cast the tensor to the given `dtype` as a parameter. If `dtype` parameter is not provided, it just returns the `dtype` of the tensor. So, the difference is the added functionality of casting.

Also, If the casting is performed to a new type, then the function returns a copy of the tensor.

Comment: the functionality is possible if tensors only have a dtype. There is no need for it to have a dtype and a type(). since casting a tensor to a different type changes both the dtype and the associated type()?

Comment: Essentially, the `dtype` attribute and `type` function without parameters on a tensor is the same. But, the `type` function provides the additional capability of type conversion. If you wanna check the implementation of the type function see [this](https://github.com/tylergenter/pytorch/blob/master/torch/_utils.py#L5).